# IOS::How can submit app to the iTunes Store[xcode 6.1.1]

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, xcode6.1

HereI'm not getting the my build in iTunes Store [Build choose option].It's working fine upto submit clicking in xcode.
Why it's not showing my build in iTunes Store. Please help me,I'm really appriciate you.

just one hour ago I have got the mail from client in that actual reason is binary with supporting 32-bit and 64-bit.But I am using the xcode 6.1.1 and in this i have only 64-bit acrhitecture.How can i implement in both 32-bit and 64-bit.In xcode build settings I am getting only architecture 64-bit.Please suggest me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have got the solution for this.This is worked for me.
**Build Active Architecture Only "NO"** ,I changed the **Deployment Target 7.0.**
and I have reduced the warnings in App.
[image]